# Constraining the key in JSON schema

Tags: json, schema

I would like to put constraints the *key* in a JSON document, using JSON schema. For example, I may have a JSON document that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "a green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

I don't care about which particular keys are being used, but I'd like to enforce in the schema that no key is longer than a certain number of characters; let's say 4 characters for the sake of argument. The example above would then fail schema validation, because "price" is 5 characters long.

I know how to validate the length of the *value* -- here, I care about the *key*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `patternProperties` to restrict property names to those that match a regular expression. In the case of your example, it might look like this:

```json
{ "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "patternProperties": {   
    "^.{1,4}$": {}
  }
}
```

Note `"additionalProperties": false` is necessary as well.